# Parse.com Windows Phone 8.1 not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, parse-platform, windows-phone-8.1

I want to ask a question regarding Parse.com on Windows Phone 8.1. I've successfully set up the SDK out there, but it crashes the app with the following error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Parse.DLL
An exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Parse.DLL but was not handled in user code
Additional information: The type initializer for 'Parse.ParseClient' threw an exception.
```

I also recognised, that Parse.com have only tutorials for windows phone 8, but we do not have devices to test 8.0. So back to the queston, will Parse work on WP 8.1 or should I look for alternatives?

Comment: Can you attach a debugger and get a stack trace?

Comment: I'd like to but I don't know how...I used Xcode before Apple pissed me off...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parse.com is no longer supported, and now it is defunct

Answer (score 0):

You must manually add reference in your Phone 8.1 project to `Parse.dll` and `Parse.WinRT.dll`, not to `ParsePhone.dll`

Comment: Given that the exception states that the error occurred in Parse.dll, I think the OP already has added the reference.